# Nested stringed son, rendering to the Angular2 HTML

Tags: angular

I have object called module

```
modules: Module[];

   this.modules = [{ id: "123", title: "newstate", organiser: "{"id":"2133","ProfileVerified":false}"}]
```

i can use this in a way like this

```
<div *ngFor="item in modules">
    {{item.title}}</div>
```

I cannot use `{{module.organiser.id}}` I assume because the organiser is a stringfyed json. So how can i more forward.

Comment: where is this data coming from? Mock data or real data?

Comment: @AJT_82 Thanks. Real-data

Comment: So how does the data look like when it arrives? Have you checked your network tab? Seems strange that the organiser looks like that when it comes? :)

Comment: And how do you assign the data? I would think that an error would be thrown, as that is not valid json,

Answer (score 0):

You put the organiser object between quotes. Making it a string instead of an object. It should be as follows:

```
   this.modules = [{ id: "123", title: "newstate", organiser: {"id":"2133","ProfileVerified":false}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to wrap the string with `'` for organiser.

Like :  `organiser: '{"id":"2133","ProfileVerified":false}'`

then create JSON object out of string. like :

`modules[0].organiser = JSON.parse(modules[0].organiser);`

then you can easily access `{{module.organiser.id}}`

I've created fiddle hope it helps. [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/f7ddqhac/)